# Kubernetes : use node labels in yaml deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I have a quick question regarding kubernetes yaml files :

can I reference a node label value in a pvc, using a node label as variable?

Something like :

```
  volumes:
    - name: data-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: main-dev-pvc-${node.failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Is the idea to force the use of PV created in a specific zone? [StorageClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) can help with that.

Custom StorageClass:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: ssd-usc1a
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
  zones: us-central1-a
```

PVC that refers to the custom storage class:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: main-dev-pvc-ssd-usc1a
  namespace: dev-project
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: ssd-usc1a
```

Assuming the same namespace as for the PVC:

```
  volumes:
    - name: data-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: main-dev-pvc-ssd-usc1a
```

Kubernetes will try to schedule the pod on a node in the same zone where the PV is (us-central1-a in the example above). Quote from the docs: "...The scheduler (via the VolumeZonePredicate predicate) will also ensure that pods that claim a given volume are only placed into the same zone as that volume, as volumes cannot be attached across zones". Therefore, the scheduling will fail if there isn't a such suitable node.

Comment: i donc think this is the exact way this can work.
My admin created 2 distinct storageClass : nfs-site1 and nfs-site2

those storage class represent nfs storage on 2 different geographic sites.

i dont think i can refer those storage classes dynamically in my deployment yaml.

am i right ? don't i need a way to tell the pod to choose the good pvc referencing the good storage class depending the current hosting node ?

Comment: @Guillaume It is the other way around - among other conditions, the scheduler determines the node where to place a pod based on the zone where the persistent volume (PV) was created by the claim (PVC). See also [Running in Multiple Zones](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/multiple-zones/). A deployment defines the volumes, including those that come from a PVC; the PVC, and thus the PV created from it, must exist before a pod is created from the deployment configuration. The StorageClass is specified in the PVC config, not in the deployment config.

Comment: thank you i am gonna take this approach
and since @Artem said there no default way to use variables in k8s yamls, i can't achieve what i tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use variables in Kubernetes yaml files by default.

But there are some tools which have such functionality, [helm](https://helm.sh/), for example. Or you can use automation tool like Ansible for creating Kubernetes resources with some parameters according to some rules.

Comment: Sadly, helm can't help me when a geosite is down and my pod is rescheduled on an other site, and has to use another pvc.